# Check the Arabic character letter position in statement according Unicode system using java

Tags: java

How to check the Arabic character letter position (start,middle,end) in statement according Unicode system using java

Comment: What *is* *"the Arabic character letter in statement position according Unicode system"*?

Comment: Only guessing what the author meant, but letters in Arabic take different forms if they appear at the starting, middle or end of a word (not really, it is more complicated than "word", but lets say that for simplification). For example, *ha* can appear in 4 forms http://arabicreadingcourse.com/images/forms/ha-forms.png. I guess they want to know, given a unicode string, whether each letter is in the start form, the middle form or the end form.

Comment: I don’t think that information is in the Unicode character database or in Java’s internal data.  You’ll probably want to build two sets manually, such as `Set<Character> wordStartChars` and `Set<Character> wordEndChars`.

Comment: AFAIK, they are still the same characters/letters. Just a different glyph/presentation is used to write it. See https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/53700. Given that there are multiple glyphs for the same character, perhaps some part of the font stack should be able to say what the type of glyph this is?

Comment: Arabic letters with different positions (start, middle, end) have different Unicode  really i saw it..... just my question about how to check position using java   ......... i don't understand your comments

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if ( Character.UnicodeBlock.ARABIC.equals( Character.UnicodeBlock.of( chr ) ) )
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: I don’t think the question is asking how to determine whether a character is Arabic.  It appears to be asking how to determine whether an Arabic character is a start-of-word character, end-of-word character, or neither.